# Spring WebFlux authenticated WebSocket connection

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-webflux, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I have running `Spring Boot@2.2.x` server with exposed WebSocket endpoint. Here is my `WebSocketConfiguration`:

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfiguration {

    private static final String WS_PATH = "/ws/notifications";

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping webSocketHandlerMapping() {
        Map<String, WebSocketHandler> handlersMap = new HashMap<>();
        handlersMap.put(WS_PATH, session -> session.send(session.receive()
                                                                .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                                                                .doOnEach(logNext(log::info))
                                                                .map(msg -> format("notification for your msg: %s", msg))
                                                                .map(session::textMessage)));

        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        handlerMapping.setUrlMap(handlersMap);
        return handlerMapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter(WebSocketService webSocketService) {
        return new WebSocketHandlerAdapter(webSocketService);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketService webSocketService() {
        return new HandshakeWebSocketService(new ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy());
    }
}
```

The question is how I can implement authentication for establishing WS connection either using `Basic Authentication` or `Bearer Authentication` or `access_token` query parameter?

*The preferable option is to avoid using Spring Security.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Websocket connection starts out life as an HTTP request that is `Upgraded`. You can do JWT token authentication before the upgrade happens. In spring boot it works as follows:

Expose a custom `WebSocketService` bean:

```java
@Bean
public WebSocketService webSocketService(RequestUpgradeStrategy upgradeStrategy) {
    return new HandshakeWebSocketService(upgradeStrategy);
}
```

Implement the `RequestUpgradeStrategy` interface in your own class:

```java
@Override
public Mono<Void> upgrade(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebSocketHandler handler, @Nullable String subProtocol, Supplier<HandshakeInfo> handshakeInfoFactory) {
    ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
    HttpServerResponse reactorResponse = getNativeResponse(response);
    HandshakeInfo handshakeInfo = handshakeInfoFactory.get();
    NettyDataBufferFactory bufferFactory = (NettyDataBufferFactory) response.bufferFactory();

    var authResult = validateAuth(handshakeInfo);
    if (authResult == unauthorised) return Mono.just(reactorResponse.status(rejectedStatus))
                                               .flatMap(HttpServerResponse::send);
    else return reactorResponse.sendWebsocket(subProtocol, //
                                              this.maxFramePayloadLength,//
                                              (in, out) -> {
                                                  ReactorNettyWebSocketSession session = new ReactorNettyWebSocketSession(in, out,
                                                                                                                          handshakeInfo,
                                                                                                                          bufferFactory,
                                                                                                                          this.maxFramePayloadLength);
                                                  return handler.handle(session);
                                              });
}
```

Notes:

- The above class is based on `ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy`.
- Returning `reactorResponse.sendWebsocket` is the existing behaviour that upgrades the connection to a WebSocket connection
- `reactorResponse.status` can be returned to stop the connection being upgraded. For example, you can return a `401` response in the case of an unauthorised connection.
- Query params and `Authentication` headers can be found in handshake info. How to do the authentication itself is outside the scope of the question.